Why does switching from reference to RefCell fail the borrow checker?
Rust (1.78.0) successfully compiles the following code:
struct Foo<'a>(&'a mut usize);
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    pub fn func(&self, _s: &'a mut String) -> &'a str {
        "hello world"
    }
}

fn test_func(arg: &Foo) {
    let mut buf = String::new();
    let _s = arg.func(&mut buf);
}

Now I change the definition of Foo to hold the reference within a RefCell:
struct Foo<'a>(std::cell::RefCell<&'a mut usize>);
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    pub fn func(&self, _s: &'a mut String) -> &'a str {
        "hello world"
    }
}

fn test_func(arg: &Foo) {
    let mut buf = String::new();
    let _s = arg.func(&mut buf);
}

This now fails:
error[E0597]: `buf` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:12:23
   |
10 | fn test_func(arg: &Foo) {
   |              --- has type `&Foo<'1>`
11 |     let mut buf = String::new();
   |         ------- binding `buf` declared here
12 |     let _s = arg.func(&mut buf);
   |              ---------^^^^^^^^-
   |              |        |
   |              |        borrowed value does not live long enough
   |              argument requires that `buf` is borrowed for `'1`
13 | }
   | - `buf` dropped here while still borrowed

Why did this change cause the borrow checker to fail, despite not modifying the function signature? Thanks for any help!

Why did the original code compile at all, given that buf's lifetime is shorter than 'a?

cause the previous code was more trivial for the compiler, the lifetime was on a reference not inside a structure. Sometime the compiler can compile code even if the code have little sense, sometime it can't. The only thing that mater is there is no regression. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ac600e204d551a9d847af491255121fd

Look into variance. In the first example 'a is covariant while in the second example it is invariant.

I understand variance, but only at the basic level of parameters and return types. If you have a more complete answer I would be grateful for you to elaborate.

You didn't switch from a reference to a RefCell you added a RefCell, that's quite a different question.

The other answer was useful, correct, and pointed me in the right direction, but didn't really address the root of my confusion, so I thought I would write up my resolution.
Previously, I falsely believed that the borrow checker checks a function's signature based on the lifetimes involved, and nothing more. But there is an additional, hidden input, which is inferred by the compiler based on the type definition.
This is non-intuitive (to me at least). When the compiler type-checks a function call, we expect it to match-up the arguments against the function's formal parameters: what happens in the function body shouldn't matter at the call site. But here what happens in the type's "body" matters a lot at the call site.
If the borrow checker only looked a lifetimes, this should not compile:
struct Foo<'a>(&'a mut usize);
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    pub fn func(&self, _s: &'a mut String) -> &'a str {
        "hello world"
    }
}

fn test_func(arg: &Foo) {
    let mut buf = String::new();
    let _s = arg.func(&mut buf);
}

Here arg has some (anonymous) lifetime and buf has a shorter lifetime, so it should be rejected: the _s param does not have a lifetime of 'a!
But there is an additional "hidden" input to the borrow checker, which the Rust compiler infers based on the type definitions. This property is called "variance" and it is a subtyping relationship, related to subtyping in OO programming.
In this case, the compiler infers (from Foo's definition) that it is valid to narrow &Foo<'long> to &Foo<'short>, which is what func does. Within func the lifetime 'a may be narrower than Foo's "real" 'a.
Whether this narrowing is allowed is hidden, with no apparent way to make it explicit, and is fragile: it may be accidentally broken by incidental changes to the type's definition. That's how lifetime errors may be introduced without actually changing any lifetimes.

If you're relying upon the variance of a type not under your control, you can easily create assertion functions that will fail to compile should the variance change/differ from your expectations.  This is really only an issue for unsafe code, but I thought I'd note it here.

Your examples aren't really equivalent, because in the first case Foo::func can't mutate the &mut usize behind &self whereas in the second case it can.
In particular, if in the first case Foo::func were to receive &mut self instead of &self, you'd hit the same error (playground):
struct Foo<'a>(&'a mut usize);
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    pub fn func(&mut self, _s: &'a mut String) -> &'a str {
        "hello world"
    }
}

fn test_func(arg: &mut Foo) {
    let mut buf = String::new();
    let _s = arg.func(&mut buf);
}

Why is this?  Because func could assign into self.0 a reference that is derived from its _s argument.  Whilst possible (with unsafe code) for usize from a String, it's easier to demonstrate if we change the field type to &mut str (playground):
struct Foo<'a>(&'a mut str);
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    pub fn func(&mut self, s: &'a mut String) -> &'a str {
        self.0 = s;
        "hello world"
    }
}

Can you see now why test_func is problematic?  When it returns, arg.0 will hold a reference to freed memory!  Undefined Behaviour.
However, Foo::func didn't receive &mut self, it received &self.  The borrow checker accepted that because, informally, mutation of the field was not possible.  When in a RefCell however, mutation is possible through the shared reference and so the call is again denied.
The more formal treatment of this informal argument, as @kmdreko said in the comments above, is by way of variance: &'a mut T is covariant in 'a whereas RefCell<&'a mut T> is invariant in 'a; consequently, Foo is respectively covariant and invariant in its lifetime parameter and so is &Foo (whereas &mut Foo is invariant in it).  See the Rustonomicon chapter on Subtyping and Variance for more information.
